# Preg_Replace (remove) Array of Exact Match Words PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-replace

I have an array of stopwords set into an array

```
$stopwords = array(
    "a ",
    "about ",
    "above ",
    "above ",
    "across ",
    "after ",
    "afterwards ",
    "again ",
    "against ",
    "all ",
    "almost ",
    "alone ",
    "along ",
    "already ",
    "also ",
    "although ",
    "always ",
    "am ",
    "among ",
    "amongst ",
    "amoungst ",
    "amount ",
    "an ",
    "and ",
    "another ",
    "any ",
    "anyhow ",
    "anyone ",
    "anything ",
    "anyway ",
    "anywhere ",
    "are ",
    "around ",
    "as ",
    "at ",
    "back ",
    "be ",
    "became ",
    "because ",
    "become ",
    "becomes ",
    "becoming ",
    "been ",
    "before ",
    "beforehand ",
    "behind ",
    "being ",
    "below ",
    "beside ",
    "besides ",
    "between ",
    "beyond ",
    "bill ",
    "both ",
    "bottom ",
    "but ",
    "by ",
    "can ",
    "cannot ",
    "cant ",
    "co ",
    "con ",
    "could ",
    "couldnt ",
    "cry ",
    "considered ",
    "describe ",
    "detail ",
    "do ",
    "did ",
    "done ",
    "down ",
    "due ",
    "during ",
    "each ",
    "eg ",
    "eight ",
    "either ",
    "eleven ",
    "else ",
    "elsewhere ",
    "empty ",
    "enough ",
    "etc ",
    "even ",
    "ever ",
    "every ",
    "everyone ",
    "everything ",
    "everywhere ",
    "except ",
    "few ",
    "fifteen ",
    "fify ",
    "fill ",
    "find ",
    "fire ",
    "five ",
    "for ",
    "former ",
    "formerly ",
    "forty ",
    "found ",
    "four ",
    "from ",
    "front ",
    "full ",
    "further ",
    "get ",
    "give ",
    "go ",
    "had ",
//    "has ",
    "hasnt ",
    "have ",
    "he ",
    "hence ",
    "her ",
    "here ",
    "hereafter ",
    "hereby ",
    "herein ",
    "hereupon ",
    "hers ",
    "herself ",
    "him ",
    "himself ",
    "his ",
    "how ",
    "however ",
    "hundred ",
    "ie ",
    "if ",
    "In",
    "inc ",
    "indeed ",
    "interest ",
    "into ",
    "is ",
    "it ",
    "its ",
    "itself ",
    "keep ",
    "known ",
//    "last ",
    "latter ",
    "latterly ",
    "least ",
    "legend ",
    "less ",
    "ltd ",
//    "made ",
    "many ",
    "may ",
    "me ",
    "meanwhile ",
    "might ",
    "mill ",
    "mine ",
    "more ",
    "moreover ",
//    "most ",
    "mostly ",
    "move ",
    "much ",
    "must ",
    "my ",
    "myself ",
    "name ",
    "namely ",
    "neither ",
    "never ",
    "nevertheless ",
    "next ",
    "nine ",
    "no ",
    "nobody ",
    "none ",
    "noone ",
    "nor ",
    "nothing ",
    "now ",
    "nowhere ",
    "of ",
    "off ",
    "often ",
    "on ",
    "once ",
    "one ",
    "only ",
    "onto ",
    "or ",
    "other ",
    "others ",
    "otherwise ",
    "our ",
    "ours ",
    "ourselves ",
    "out ",
//    "over ",
    "own ",
    "part ",
    "per ",
    "perhaps ",
    "please ",
    "popular ",
    "put ",
    "rather ",
    "re ",
    "same ",
    "see ",
    "seem ",
    "seemed ",
    "seeming ",
    "seems ",
    "serious ",
    "several ",
    "she ",
    "should ",
    "show ",
    "since ",
    "sincere ",
    "six ",
    "sixty ",
    "so ",
    "some ",
    "somehow ",
    "someone ",
    "something ",
    "sometime ",
    "sometimes ",
    "somewhere ",
    "still ",
    "such ",
    "take ",
    "technique ",
    "ten ",
    "than ",
    "that ",
    "the ",
    "their ",
    "them ",
    "themselves ",
    "then ",
    "thence ",
    "there ",
    "thereafter ",
    "thereby ",
    "therefore ",
    "therein ",
    "thereupon ",
    "these ",
    "they ",
    "thickv ",
    "term ",
    "thin ",
    "third ",
    "this ",
    "those ",
    "though ",
    "three ",
    "through ",
    "throughout ",
    "thru ",
    "thus ",
    "to ",
    "together ",
    "too ",
    "top ",
    "toward ",
    "towards ",
    "twelve ",
    "twenty ",
    "two ",
    "un ",
    "under ",
    "until ",
    "up ",
    "upon ",
    "us ",
    "very ",
    "via ",
    "was ",
    "we ",
    "well ",
    "were ",
    "what ",
    "whatever ",
    "when ",
    "whence ",
    "whenever ",
    "where ",
    "whereafter ",
    "whereas ",
    "whereby ",
    "wherein ",
    "whereupon ",
    "wherever ",
    "whether ",
    "which ",
    "while ",
    "whither ",
    "who ",
    "whoever ",
    "whole ",
    "whom ",
    "whose ",
    "why ",
    "will ",
    "with ",
    "within ",
    "without ",
    "would ",
    "yet ",
    "you ",
    "your ",
    "yours ",
    "yourself ",
    "yourselves ",
    "the ",
    "likely ",
    "names "
);
```

You may have noticed by the space after I was trying to avoid cutting off strings and want to only replace whole matches (to a NULL value) from my stopword list.

Realizing that str_replace is probably secondary to capabilities and benefits, I turned my eye towards building a preg_replace array in attempt to regex whole words using word boundaries.

```
$pregreplacestopwords = array(
"/\ba\b/",
"/\babout\b/",
"/\babove\b/",
"/\babove\b/",
"/\bacross\b/",
"/\bafter\b/",
"/\bafterwards\b/",
"/\bagain\b/",
"/\bagainst\b/",
"/\ball\b/",
"/\balmost\b/",
"/\balone\b/",
"/\balong\b/",
"/\balready\b/",
"/\balso\b/",
"/\balthough\b/",
"/\balways\b/",
"/\bam\b/",
"/\bamong\b/",
"/\bamongst\b/",
"/\bamoungst\b/",
"/\bamount\b/",
"/\ban\b/",
"/\band\b/",
"/\banother\b/",
"/\bany\b/",
"/\banyhow\b/",
"/\banyone\b/",
"/\banything\b/",
"/\banyway\b/",
"/\banywhere\b/",
"/\bare\b/",
"/\baround\b/",
"/\bas\b/",
"/\bat\b/",
"/\bback\b/",
"/\bbe\b/",
"/\bbecame\b/",
"/\bbecause\b/",
"/\bbecome\b/",
"/\bbecomes\b/",
"/\bbecoming\b/",
"/\bbeen\b/",
"/\bbefore\b/",
"/\bbeforehand\b/",
"/\bbehind\b/",
"/\bbeing\b/",
"/\bbelow\b/",
"/\bbeside\b/",
"/\bbesides\b/",
"/\bbetween\b/",
"/\bbeyond\b/",
"/\bbill\b/",
"/\bboth\b/",
"/\bbottom\b/",
"/\bbut\b/",
"/\bby\b/",
"/\bcan\b/",
"/\bcannot\b/",
"/\bcant\b/",
"/\bco\b/",
"/\bcon\b/",
"/\bcould\b/",
"/\bcouldnt\b/",
"/\bcry\b/",
"/\bconsidered\b/",
"/\bdescribe\b/",
"/\bdetail\b/",
"/\bdo\b/",
"/\bdid\b/",
"/\bdone\b/",
"/\bdown\b/",
"/\bdue\b/",
"/\bduring\b/",
"/\beach\b/",
"/\beg\b/",
"/\beight\b/",
"/\beither\b/",
"/\beleven\b/",
"/\belse\b/",
"/\belsewhere\b/",
"/\bempty\b/",
"/\benough\b/",
"/\betc\b/",
"/\beven\b/",
"/\bever\b/",
"/\bevery\b/",
"/\beveryone\b/",
"/\beverything\b/",
"/\beverywhere\b/",
"/\bexcept\b/",
"/\bfew\b/",
"/\bfifteen\b/",
"/\bfify\b/",
"/\bfill\b/",
"/\bfind\b/",
"/\bfire\b/",
"/\bfive\b/",
"/\bfor\b/",
"/\bformer\b/",
"/\bformerly\b/",
"/\bforty\b/",
"/\bfound\b/",
"/\bfour\b/",
"/\bfrom\b/",
"/\bfront\b/",
"/\bfull\b/",
"/\bfurther\b/",
"/\bget\b/",
"/\bgive\b/",
"/\bgo\b/",
"/\bhad\b/",
"/\b//has\b/",
"/\bhasnt\b/",
"/\bhave\b/",
"/\bhe\b/",
"/\bhence\b/",
"/\bher\b/",
"/\bhere\b/",
"/\bhereafter\b/",
"/\bhereby\b/",
"/\bherein\b/",
"/\bhereupon\b/",
"/\bhers\b/",
"/\bherself\b/",
"/\bhim\b/",
"/\bhimself\b/",
"/\bhis\b/",
"/\bhow\b/",
"/\bhowever\b/",
"/\bhundred\b/",
"/\bie\b/",
"/\bif\b/",
"/\bIn\b/",
"/\binc\b/",
"/\bindeed\b/",
"/\binterest\b/",
"/\binto\b/",
"/\bis\b/",
"/\bit\b/",
"/\bits\b/",
"/\bitself\b/",
"/\bkeep\b/",
"/\bknown\b/",
"/\b//last\b/",
"/\blatter\b/",
"/\blatterly\b/",
"/\bleast\b/",
"/\blegend\b/",
"/\bless\b/",
"/\bltd\b/",
"/\b//made\b/",
"/\bmany\b/",
"/\bmay\b/",
"/\bme\b/",
"/\bmeanwhile\b/",
"/\bmight\b/",
"/\bmill\b/",
"/\bmine\b/",
"/\bmore\b/",
"/\bmoreover\b/",
"/\bmost\b/",
"/\bmostly\b/",
"/\bmove\b/",
"/\bmuch\b/",
"/\bmust\b/",
"/\bmy\b/",
"/\bmyself\b/",
"/\bname\b/",
"/\bnamely\b/",
"/\bneither\b/",
"/\bnever\b/",
"/\bnevertheless\b/",
"/\bnext\b/",
"/\bnine\b/",
"/\bno\b/",
"/\bnobody\b/",
"/\bnone\b/",
"/\bnoone\b/",
"/\bnor\b/",
"/\bnothing\b/",
"/\bnow\b/",
"/\bnowhere\b/",
"/\bof\b/",
"/\boff\b/",
"/\boften\b/",
"/\bon\b/",
"/\bonce\b/",
"/\bone\b/",
"/\bonly\b/",
"/\bonto\b/",
"/\bor\b/",
"/\bother\b/",
"/\bothers\b/",
"/\botherwise\b/",
"/\bour\b/",
"/\bours\b/",
"/\bourselves\b/",
"/\bout\b/",
"/\b//over\b/",
"/\bown\b/",
"/\bpart\b/",
"/\bper\b/",
"/\bperhaps\b/",
"/\bplease\b/",
"/\bpopular\b/",
"/\bput\b/",
"/\brather\b/",
"/\bre\b/",
"/\bsame\b/",
"/\bsee\b/",
"/\bseem\b/",
"/\bseemed\b/",
"/\bseeming\b/",
"/\bseems\b/",
"/\bserious\b/",
"/\bseveral\b/",
"/\bshe\b/",
"/\bshould\b/",
"/\bshow\b/",
"/\bsince\b/",
"/\bsincere\b/",
"/\bsix\b/",
"/\bsixty\b/",
"/\bso\b/",
"/\bsome\b/",
"/\bsomehow\b/",
"/\bsomeone\b/",
"/\bsomething\b/",
"/\bsometime\b/",
"/\bsometimes\b/",
"/\bsomewhere\b/",
"/\bstill\b/",
"/\bsuch\b/",
"/\btake\b/",
"/\btechnique\b/",
"/\bten\b/",
"/\bthan\b/",
"/\bthat\b/",
"/\bthe\b/",
"/\btheir\b/",
"/\bthem\b/",
"/\bthemselves\b/",
"/\bthen\b/",
"/\bthence\b/",
"/\bthere\b/",
"/\bthereafter\b/",
"/\bthereby\b/",
"/\btherefore\b/",
"/\btherein\b/",
"/\bthereupon\b/",
"/\bthese\b/",
"/\bthey\b/",
"/\bthickv\b/",
"/\bterm\b/",
"/\bthin\b/",
"/\bthird\b/",
"/\bthis\b/",
"/\bthose\b/",
"/\bthough\b/",
"/\bthree\b/",
"/\bthrough\b/",
"/\bthroughout\b/",
"/\bthru\b/",
"/\bthus\b/",
"/\bto\b/",
"/\btogether\b/",
"/\btoo\b/",
"/\btop\b/",
"/\btoward\b/",
"/\btowards\b/",
"/\btwelve\b/",
"/\btwenty\b/",
"/\btwo\b/",
"/\bun\b/",
"/\bunder\b/",
"/\buntil\b/",
"/\bup\b/",
"/\bupon\b/",
"/\bus\b/",
"/\bvery\b/",
"/\bvia\b/",
"/\bwas\b/",
"/\bwe\b/",
"/\bwell\b/",
"/\bwere\b/",
"/\bwhat\b/",
"/\bwhatever\b/",
"/\bwhen\b/",
"/\bwhence\b/",
"/\bwhenever\b/",
"/\bwhere\b/",
"/\bwhereafter\b/",
"/\bwhereas\b/",
"/\bwhereby\b/",
"/\bwherein\b/",
"/\bwhereupon\b/",
"/\bwherever\b/",
"/\bwhether\b/",
"/\bwhich\b/",
"/\bwhile\b/",
"/\bwhither\b/",
"/\bwho\b/",
"/\bwhoever\b/",
"/\bwhole\b/",
"/\bwhom\b/",
"/\bwhose\b/",
"/\bwhy\b/",
"/\bwill\b/",
"/\bwith\b/",
"/\bwithin\b/",
"/\bwithout\b/",
"/\bwould\b/",
"/\byet\b/",
"/\byou\b/",
"/\byour\b/",
"/\byours\b/",
"/\byourself\b/",
"/\byourselves\b/",
"/\bthe\b/",
"/\blikely\b/",
"/\bnames\b/"
        );
```

Created a blank array for it:

```
$pgreplace = array(" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ");
```

Let's take the word `“B.A.”` for example and put it into a string variable, make it a sentence for fun.

```
 $string = 'I got my “B.A.” from...';
```

Some methods I've tried have been things such as imploding the stop words,

Attempting things such as

preg_replace($pregreplacestopwords, $pregreplacestopwords, $string);

Just get's filled with errors

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 1951 in C:\wamp64\www\pg\test.php on line 664

Warning: preg_replace(): Empty regular expression in C:\wamp64\www\pg\test.php on line 666
NULL 
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '/' in C:\wamp64\www\pg\test.php on line 670
NULL
```

Imploding the array, via`$implodestopwords = implode("|", array_map("trim",array_filter($stopwords)));`

> a|about|above|above|across|after|afterwards|again|against|all|almost|alone|along|already|also

and so forth.

Trying to put this in action

```
$pattern = '/\b(' . $implodestopwords . ')\b/i';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, "", $string);

var_dump($string);
```

outputs:

> I got “B..” ...

How can I modify my preg_replace to only match exact words and remove them from a large list of words from an array?

Full script here: https://pastebin.com/vwbNjhs9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe instead of using preg_replace() you might just try turning your string into an array and then looping over it checking if each word is in your stop words array.

Try this and see if it works:

```
$string = 'I got my "B.A." from...';
$string = preg_replace('/\s{1,}/', ' ', $string); //<--insure only one space between characters.
$array = explode(' ', $string);

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){

  if(in_array($array[$i] . ' ', $stopwords)){ //<-- Only concatenated space because of your
  //trailing spaces in the stopwords array.

    $array[$i] = '';  //<--Removed the word.

  }

}

$newString = implode(' ', $array);  //<--Turn the array back to a string.

echo $newString; //<---Outputs "I got "B.A." from...".
```

This method gives you a lot of control over what you decide to do with each found word.

Comment: That works thank you. I was looking into something like this but really nice to see coded and commented as such it so well done. I was thinking there was a way to preg_replace an array of strings similiar to how str_replace allows arrays of strings (but not word boundaries and other such things as preg_replace, obviously). Is there no way to use preg_replace as outlined above from an array of words? I know it accepts an array but it seems hard to implement and couldn't find a whole lot out there.  Anyways I will accept for now thanks again.

Comment: Thank you, but.... PHP.net says that if your not using any fancy regex and your just doing word replacement that you should use str_replace.  That being said, I would use the str_ireplace which is not case sensitive.